# MySQL Group Replication consistency EVENTUAL vs BEFORE_ON_PRIMARY_FAILOVER

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-innodb-cluster, group-replication

As far as I understand, `BEFORE_ON_PRIMARY_FAILOVER` is exactly behaving like `EVENTUAL` in normal scenarios until a failover happened, which the former will block all new transactions until the new primary node has applied its backlog while the latter allows transactions to be run immediately.

I have tried both options in the lab environment. When the replication lag is relatively high, it takes a very long time for the new primary to apply backlog and open to new transactions. This significantly affects HA, render the auto-failover feature of Group Replication almost meaningless.

So my question is, is that really beneficial to use `BEFORE_ON_PRIMARY_FAILOVER` instead of `EVENTUAL`? Is that really a "safer" option?

Some info about my environment in case that matters:
MySQL 8.0.25, installed using TAR ball format.
RHEL: 8.0

Comment: Let's work on why the replication lag is high.  There are many reasons why it should be kept low.  Are there multiple apply threads?  Are there slow queries?  Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes a DBA's blood run cold the most is *split-brain*.

That's the term for the scenario where you start writing updates to one of the nodes in a cluster while it is still applying updates replicated from one of the other nodes. So you have a high chance of committing an update to some row of data, but then it is overwritten by a replicated change that originally occurred earlier.

Then the transaction you just committed executes on the other node. But the change is based on an outdated version of data, so it has the wrong values. Now neither node has the "true" state of data.

Recovering from this kind of mistake is incredibly difficult. You'd have to reconstruct the correct sequence of changes from logs somehow, then restore the whole cluster from backup, then re-run the changes in the correct order. And of course the application owner says you must do it without downtime, so you can't interrupt ongoing traffic or take the database offline to restore it.

It's virtually impossible to do this, but you soon have managers all the way up the hierarchy yelling at you to fix it immediately.

This is why synchronous replication is worth it, even if it delays failover. It protects against split-brain, which is, frankly, more important than high throughput.

If you have frequent replication lag, switching to EVENTUAL is not a good solution. The solution is either to reduce the query traffic, or increase the server's performance, until the group replication cluster can keep up with it without causing frequent replication lag.

This is done in one of two ways:

- **Scale up:** get faster CPUs, faster storage drives, more RAM.
- **Scale out:** split the data over multiple clusters, and distribute data updates more or less evenly between the clusters, so each cluster only needs to handle a fraction of the traffic.

Or eventually, you need to use both solutions, because there's only so far you can scale up.

Comment: So based on that, is it theoretically better to allow R/O and block write only operations while applying changes? This at least allows partial recovery of service.

Comment: Even if you only allow read queries, you risk reading data that is out of date. That is, you could read current data on the old primary, then a failover occurs, and then you try to read on the new primary node but you can only see old data until replication catches up. Is this what you want? It might cause a lot of confusion. This depends on your app's requirements, so there's no way we can answer this for you.